# Concurrent Calls to Oracle WebLogic 10.3 Web Service Problems

Tags: web-services, concurrency, weblogic

I have a Web Service (in java) on a Oracle WebLogic 10.3 that does all kinds of database queries. Recently I started stress tests. It passed the repetition tests (invoke the WS several 1000 times serially) but problems become to arise when concurrency testing began. Making as much as 2 concurrent calls results in errors. When doing proper tests the results looked like the WS wasn't able to handle concurrent calls at all, which obviously should not be the case. Error included null pointer exceptions, closed connections or prepared statements, etc. I am bit stumped at this specially since I was unable to find any kind of configuration options that could effect this but then again my knowledge of the WLS is quite limited.

Thanks for any suggestions in advance.

Comment: Are you sure its weblogic and not your app sharing data incorrectly?

Comment: Yes, I came to the same unfortunate conclusion. When I was creating the Web Services I though that WebLogic uses pooling for concurrent calls but it seems that was not the case. This mistake probably resulted from my rather limited knowledge of WebLogic. I fixed the services so they would be Thread-safe and now it works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just so there is a clear answer.

When there are several concurrent calls to a given Web Service (in this case SOAP/JAX-WS was used) on WLS, the same object is used (no pooling or queues are used), therefore the implementation must be thread safe.

EDIT:

To clarify:
Assume there is a class attribute in the WebService implementation class generated by JDeveloper. If you modify this attribute in your web method (and then use it) it will cause synchronization problems when the method is called (ie WS is called) concurrently. When I first started creating web services I though the whole WebService object was created anew for each WS call but this does not seem to be the case.

Answer (score 0):

The answer you marked as correct is totally wrong.

The webservice methods should not be made in order to be thread safe.

Webservice implenmtation of weblogic are multithreaded.

It's like for the servlets

"Servlets are multithreaded. Servlet-based applications have to recognize and handle this appropriately. If large sections of code are synchronized, an application effectively becomes single threaded, and throughput decreases dramatically."

http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/websphere/library/bestpractices/avoiding_or_minimizing_synchronization_in_servlets.html

The code inside the WS you might want to synchronize depending what you do.

[Does it make sense to synchronize web-service method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5904907/does-it-make-sense-to-synchronize-web-service-method)

Comment: Ignoring the fact that this does not answer the actual question, I think you miss understood what I was talking about (or more likely I had not explained my self very well). I am far from an expert on the matter so I just say it as I see it. If there is a class attribute in the WebService implementation class generated by JDeveloper and it is changed in the web method, then this will cause synchronization problems when the method is called (ie WS is called) concurrently. It is a rookie mistake but then I did ask this question a year a go. I will edit the answer.